# How can I change the size of an image without cropping?

Tags: javascript, css, resize

I have an image source:

```
var _img = <img src="../images/yadayada.jpg">
```

And I want it enlarge it or shrink it without cropping it, but I'd rather not grab the element after and change the css.

I tried:

```
_img.height = 200;
```

and

```
_img.style.height = 200
```

But the first crops it, and the second does nothing.

Comment: Please remove the txtspk from your title.

Comment: You could try adding a Style="" attribute to the property and put the height in there.

Comment: It should just be re-sizing it, not cropping it.  Is it chopping off part of the image or just making it smaller?

Comment: It's chopping off part of the image

Comment: @RobertHarvey what's `txtspk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style values need units so the style setting would be like this:

```
_img.style.height = "200px";
```

This will change the scaled size of the image.  If you only set just the height or just the width, then the other should scale to maintain the aspect ratio.  You will have to make sure that the HTML layout the image is positioned in is flexible and can handle the image changing size.

Image resize demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/K8GJQ/

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell if you're trying to change an existing image or set dimensions for a new image you're trying to create...

The statement `var _img = <img src="../images/yadayada.jpg">` won't do anything by itself except cause your JS to fail to load (it's just a string, and is missing surrounding quotes and semicolon).

If you're trying to target an image that's already in the HTML, give its `<img>` tag a unique ID that you can target, and then set the width or height.

In the HTML: `<img id="yadayadaImage">`

In the JS:

```
var myImage = document.getElementById('yadayadaImage');
myImage.style.width = "200px";
```

Setting only style.width OR style.height here should keep the image from being cropped, since the other dimension should expand automatically. If it's still cropped check the parent element's width & height attributes, because that may be what's restricting the size.

.

If you're actually trying to create a *new* image w/specific source and dimensions, what you had above won't work. You need to create a new`<img>` element with those attributes, then append it to the document.

```
var targetDiv = document.getElementById("myPhotoDiv");    
var imgTag = document.createElement('img');              
imgTag.id = "yadayadaImage";                         
imgTag.className = "uncroppedImage";               
imgTag.src = "../images/yadayada.jpeg"; 

//you COULD set height & width properties here, but that's what CSS is for. 
imgTag.style.width = "200px";

targetDiv.appendChild(imgTag); //add the new img to the page
```

The best approach, but which you said you didn't want to do, is to use CSS and create a class that you can reuse for other images where you don't necessarily know the specific width or height.

```
.uncroppedImage{
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better setup an id for your image like this

```
<img id="myImg" src="../images/yadayada.jpg">
```

and use the script below

```
var myImg = document.getElementById('myImg');
if(myImg && myImg.style) {
    myImg.style.height = '200px';
}
```